# Android passing Context everywhere

Tags: java, android, android-context

I've developed an Android App that (for me) it's so ugly and i'm pretty sure that my approach is very wrong.

I have a bunch of fragments activities and a lot of classes like async-tasks, business rules and so on. In special, I have a class called PropertiesReader that I use to read a properties file. I use this class in a lot of places like fragments and on business rules.

```
public class PropertyReader {

    private Properties properties;

    public PropertyReader(Context context){
        super();
        try {
            properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(context.getResources().getAssets().open("badass.properties"));
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("Error", "Error opening properties file", e);
        }
    }

    public String getValue(String key){
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }
}
```

In every place that i use this class, I do something like:

```
 PropertyReader bla = new PropertyReader(this); //or new PropertyReader(context);
```

I was wondering what is the best approach to work with classes that need Context to be constructed. In my opinion, it's very ugly that every constructor has a Context parameter.

Any ideas?

Thank in advance.

Comment: why don't you make it a singleton and instantiate it in your application class at first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a singleton, and save the application context on creation.

It would look something like this:

```
public class PropertyReader {

    private static PropertyReader ourInstance = new PropertyReader();
    private Context mContext;

    public static PropertyReader getInstance() {
         return ourInstance;
    }

    private PropertyReader() {
    }

    public void loadProperties(Context context) {
         mContext = context;
         try {
             properties = new Properties();
             properties.load(context.getResources().getAssets().open("badass.properties"));
         } catch (IOException e){
             Log.e("Error", "Error opening properties file", e);
         }
    }

}
```

When you application is starting up you can do something like:

```
PropertyReader.getInstance().loadProperties(getApplicationContext());
```

And then you can just access your PropertyReader everywhere else:

```
PropertyReader.getInstance().getValue(key);
```